# Where can I find the "PiMotor" library?

Tags: dc-motor

The Motor Shield from SB Components needs the 'import' of "Pi Motor" but after several lengthy searches I am still unable to find it. Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 3):

The library source code is linked to from the [SB Components website](http://www.sb-components.co.uk/motor-shield.html), where there is a link:

> [Get the library source code from GitHub](https://sbcshop.github.io/motor-shield/)

This leads you to this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/sbcshop/motor-shield), which contains `PiMotor.py`, which would seem to be the library you want.

Simply download that repository, extract the files to the directory of your script, and then running `import PiMotor` should work as expected in your script. If you're not familiar with why that will work, you might find the ["Import System" documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) valuable to read.